# Unable to start device (svg)

Tags: r, knitr

I am getting following Knitting error.

[image]

I understand that it is related with my chunk, however I am unable to fix it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the upper part of this Rmd file? What is the setting of the  output?

Comment: ---
title: "abcde"
author: "xxxx"
subtitle: 
output: 
  html_notebook: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: default
---

Comment: Sorry I failed to reproduce your error message. Accoring to this you can try `dev.off()`
https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-initiate-png-device-rnotebook/3658/2

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error. restarting RStudio solved it. It seems that it tries to find some temp files which are not available anymore.